# Flutter apps crash upon webview loaded

Tags: flutter, webview

I am trying to open a payment url link from my flutter apps webView but just crash while typing input field.

```
return Scaffold(
          body: new MyWebView(
            selectedUrl:"https://easternbank.ap.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/pay/SESSION0002887307683L1130761K87",),
        );
```

our MyWebView widget is :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class MyWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String selectedUrl;
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =  Completer<WebViewController>();
  MyWebView({
    @required this.selectedUrl,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isLoading = true;
    return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                //new LinearProgressIndicator(),
                new WebView(
                  initialUrl: selectedUrl,
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                    _controller.complete(webViewController);
                  },
                  onPageFinished: (finised) {
                    setState(() {
                      isLoading = false;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                isLoading ? _loadingScreen() : Container(),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

is there any issue with the webView for secured payment page?

It is mostly happened while trying to input something in the page

some of debug error:

```
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:9/PSR1.180720.075/5124027:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 10040, tid: 10040, name: cker.my_payment  >>> com.gomaxtracker.my_payment <<<
signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 0xd247d0d0
Abort message: '[FATAL:jni_android.cc(256)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
'    eax 00000000  ebx d4e06e2c  ecx cbbe3320  edx 00000400
    edi ff9eefe8  esi ff9eebb8
    ebp ff9eeb71  esp ff9eeb70  eip d247d0d0
backtrace:
    #00 pc 023310d0  /system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk (offset 0x1022000)
```

Comment: Include code of `MyWebView` too

Comment: now I have already inclued the MyWebView widget page too

Answer (score 0):

> *is there any issue with the webView for secured payment page?*
>
> No. But right now it does not work when the web page has **DropDown** in it.

As your app is crashing on the dropdown selection, unfortunately, is this issue is not fixed in the official plugin,
this issue is being discussed [here](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/182) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25767) and not fixed yet,

so I would suggest using [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin),

Example

```
 WebviewScaffold(
      url: "https://easternbank.ap.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/pay/SESSION0002887307683L1130761K87",
      ),
```

Comment: it's loaded nicely for the first time... and if try to input something then it just crash

Comment: then it must be crashing on dropdown

Comment: yes.. while we try to fillup the month or expired date then it crash

Comment: Please check my updated answer, I have tested this myself it works

Comment: but if i use WebViewScaffold() it overlap my drawer menu... is there any way to solve the overlapping issue?

Comment: No, but you can take it as a separate page. for now, it is the only option left.

Comment: thanks for your response..... you mean separate page without any drawer menu ?.. then how can i return to my homepage?

Comment: by `Nagator.of(context).pop();`